# Mysql java executeUpdate error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

When i use this query I have this error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:04:44,
>   23-09-2014 12:04:44)' at line 1

This is the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // creo l'oggetto
String dataStr = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(dataStr); 

// eseguo una query

/*stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO incomeCalc(c_timestamp, parent_uid, uid, status, username, password, token, enable_webservices, "
    + "webservices_ip, name, mobile, email, sender, footer, address, city, state, country, zipcode, credit, datetime_timezone,"
    + "lang  uage_module, fwd_to_mobile, fwd_to_email, fwd_to_inbox, replace_zero, plus_  sign_remove, plus_sign_add, "
    + "send_as_unicode, local_length, register_datetime, lastupdate_datetime,) " */

stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO playsms_tblUser(parent_uid, status, username, password, token, enable_webservices, credit, datetime_timezone, language_module, register_datetime, lastupdate_datetime)" 
    + "VALUES (1, 4, "+user+", MD5("+password+"), MD5("+password+"), 1, "+initialCredit+", +0100, en_US, "+dataStr+", "+dataStr+")");
db.close();
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Why don't you use *PreparedSatement*? Then you don't need to carry about quotes and formatting.

Comment: perfect, i have used PreparedStatement and it works

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the username is of type varchar? Then you should add the single quotes around it. Same goes for date.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO playsms_tblUser(parent_uid, status, username, password, token, enable_webservices, credit, datetime_timezone, language_module, register_datetime, lastupdate_datetime)" 
+ "VALUES (1, 4, '"+user+"', MD5("+password+"), MD5("+password+"), 1, "+initialCredit+", +0100, en_US, '"+dataStr+"', '"+dataStr+"')");
```

db.close();